# How to do leave one out cross validation in time series analysis?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on time series analysis and try to develop the regression model but my predator length is less than 40 year. thus to validated this model I am trying to leave one out cross validation model but I don't have an idea about to do.

Comment: What is your question / problem? Please note that this site is about how to use tools, if your question is about how to set up your model, or what statistical method to use, then that probably better fit to statistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, even if this is on-topic here, the question doesn't provide enough detail for anyone to be able to help, or even to understand the specific issue you're facing.